# Automatic csv file download from oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

I run queries on oracle 11g and then click on download button to download csv file but I want automatic download after record is inserted in table.

Answer (score 0):

"Automatically after something happens" smells like a **database trigger**.

It can not "click the download button", so you'd have to write a piece of code, i.e. utilize the `UTL_FILE` package in order to create that file.

Though, what will you do with all those files?